# Google Drive - use WebViewLink vs thumbnailLink

Tags: api, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API where I can gain access to 2 pieces of data that I need to display a jpg file oin my program. `WebViewLink` is the "large" size image while `thumbnailLink` is the "thumb" smaller size of the same image.

I'm having an issue with downloading the WebViewLink that I do not have with the thumbnailLink.  Part of my code calls either `exif_imagetype($filename)` or `getimagesize($filename)` so I can retrieve the type, height & width etc for the $`filename`.  This is successful for the thumbnailView but not the WebViewLink...

code snippet...

```
$WebViewLink = "https://drive.google.com/a/treering.com/file/d/blablabla";
$type = exif_imagetype($WebViewLink);
--- results in the error
"PHP Warning:  exif_imagetype(): stream does not support seeking..."
```

where as...

```
$thumbnailLink = "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/blablabla";
$type = exif_imagetype($thumbnailLink);
---  successful 
where $type = 2 // a .jpg file
```

Not sure what I need to do to gain a usable WebViewLink...  maybe use the "export" function to copy to a file on my server that is accessible, then use that exported file for the functions that fail above?

Thanks for any help.

John

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong property to get the image of the file.

---

## [WebViewLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

> A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.

---

## [thumbnailLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

> A short-lived link to the file's thumbnail, if available. Typically lasts on the order of hours.

You can try using the [`iconLink()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource):

> A static, unauthenticated link to the file's icon.

Sample image of thumbnailLink:

[image]

Sample image of a iconLink:

[image]

It will still show relevant image about the file.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but not exactly what I was looking for...  What I was getting at was - I can take a thumbnailLink if an image file and upload it into my system to use with no issues. What I need to do is find out what type of file it is and to do that I call exif_imagetype($thumbnailLink); which works.  However I wanted to get a larger version, not a thumb, so that I have better resolution after I upload the file and use it in my program.  Using the only other usable link that seemed to return me a larger version was WebViewLink, but the exif_imagetype() on that link fails...

Comment: BTW: seems that "export" can only be used on "Google Doc" files

Comment: You can always change the size of the thumbnail size by changing the sz variable to your preferred size (default is 220). For example :`https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=DOC_ID&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAV5nHxn04tB1xoYSqvTrUBYqqb85ap1lZ&sz=s1020` and webViewLink is not use for that purpose base on document it is "for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser."

Comment: Does changing the sz parameter change (upgrade) the resolution or use a higher resolution image when you increase the sz parameter?  If it's not a high resolution image and just an upsizing of the thumbnail, it will not work for me.  I need access to the "original" uploaded image, meaning original width & height and resolution as it was uploaded

Comment: I thought I had this solved yesterday when I used the returned "webContentLink" and removed the "&export=download", it seemed that this form of the file was returning no errors from my exif_imageType() call - however today I' receiving errors...  I have tried setting the thumbnailLink s=220 to a higher number such as you suggest s=1024, which returns me a larger image, but the resolution is lower. The URL you provided above is not returned from the google files API call - can you further explain where that's from and the params to seed it?  Thanks

Comment: Again, I want access to the "original" image, sizes and resolution, a thumbnail which is not the same resolution (dpi) as the original, sized up to be a bigger image will not do for me.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: you might be trying webContentLink or AlternateLink